# Is it possible to transform cell L2 in this google sheet into an array formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(EQ($I2:$I,$I2)*$C2:C)))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oAUNg9Kq119T4io4oHTGbvp1Klsd2SuGu3G1fs3bnhM/edit#gid=0

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeglV.png)

Comment: please share your sheet to be publicly available

Comment: I am trying to check when the data on that line was last edited

Comment: It is now publicly available

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want it to go to the other cells:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",MAX(EQ($I2:$I,$I2:I)*$C2:C)))`

Anyway, I would like to say that when in your original formula are doing `EQ($I2:$I,$I2)`, it will return always `TRUE` as you are searching in a place where the cell you are looking for is there.

This will make the whole formula only return the latest value of all of the values in the `column C`. Your implementation will always return the value in the corresponding `C` column: L2 = C2, L3 = C3 and so on. So if you want your formula to match the rows in the `column C`, you can set this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",$C2:C))`

Comment: The first formula you suggested only outputs the same date for the whole column so seems not to work, the second one at a first glance looks ok, but for some reason the labels on the column named "obsolete" which depend on this column "L" , gets messed up (many rows that should be obsolete show as "current"). Do you know why?

Comment: Can you indicate which specific rows have "Current" in column K, where you expect them to be "Obsolete"?  I see only four rows as Obsolete, where the status in J is "Deleted".  But since for all the other rows, the "Latest Occurence" date in L is always equal to the "Updated" date in C - because we copy from C to L with the ArrayFormula in L2 - these records are all marked as "Current".  Are we misunderstanding something?  Or is there some error in the data?  Or should the formula in L2 not copy the dates from column C?

Comment: For example rows 11 to 15 should be "obsolete". I don't know but I suspect the formula does something more .